# Read header key value from the response header React Js

Tags: javascript, rest

[console snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHypw.jpg)I am calling one fetch API which giving the response header 'key-name':'value'. I checked in the chrome developer tools network tab. It showing the value. However, I am trying to read it during API response it's showing empty. I tried multiple ways but still not working. Below is my code.

```
const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    pid: d,
                    cy: v
                }
                )
            };
                
  fetch('https://mysite/api/manage/', requestOptions)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(jsong => {
                    console.log(jsong);
            console.log(jsong.headers); 
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

Please help. I added a console snapshot and network response snapshot as well. [network response snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9RoT.jpg)

Comment: I don't think header values will be in the JSON response body. Maybe check for them in the `res` response object.

Comment: yes. I am trying to read after the fetch request as well it's showing empty.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution and here is the answer. It might be useful for someone

```
fetch('mysite.com/api/manage-cart/', requestOptions)
            .then(res => res.headers.get('cart_info')
            )
            .then(res => {
                window.localStorage.setItem("cartData", JSON.stringify(res));
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }); .
```

I am storing the value on local storage for further use.

Comment: If all you needed to extract from the headers was the data you originally sent, why not just reference the data payload from `requestOptions` in the success handling?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the response header values from the returned response object `res`.

[Fetch response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers#example)

[Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers)

> An object implementing `Headers` can directly be used in a `for...of`
> structure, instead of `entries()`: `for (var p of myHeaders)` is
> equivalent to `for (var p of myHeaders.entries())`.

```
fetch('https://mysite/api/manage/', requestOptions)
  .then(res => {
    for (let entry of res.headers) { // <-- response header iterable
      console.log(entry);
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); 
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

When manually making a request to "https://sandbox.zeroite.com/api/manage-cart/" these are the header entries output:

```
VM7366:11 (2) ["access-control-allow-credentials", "true"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["allow", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["cart-info", "{'product_info': {'5': 1}}"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["connection", "Keep-Alive"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["content-language", "en"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["content-length", "203"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["content-type", "application/json"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["date", "Sat, 20 Mar 2021 05:53:28 GMT"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["keep-alive", "timeout=5, max=100"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["server", "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["vary", "Accept,Accept-Language,Cookie,Origin"]
VM7366:11 (2) ["x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN"]
```

Comment: I tried this but its giving blank Headers object. However in network tab I can see the response header cart_info: {'product_info': {'1': 1}}

Comment: @nitinkumar I'll be honest, none of that looks like a response header key or value. can you share your response from the network tab? (formatted text snippet, or screenshot)

Comment: I have added both console and network snapshot. Please advise

Comment: @nitinkumar Very interesting! Is your API endpoint publicly accessible? I'd like to try hitting it from a sandbox.

Comment: yes it's accessible this is post API actually you can hit it in the browser.  https://sandbox.zeroite.com/api/manage-cart/

Comment: @nitinkumar Do you have an example payload or example request? Whatever I'm trying ends with errors.

Comment: I am sending the product id and quantity during the call. you can try this 
{product_id: 5, cart_quantity: 1}.  here is the code    const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    product_id: d,
                cart_quantity: v
                }
                )
            };

Comment: @nitinkumar did a little digging and have an updated answer, please check it.

Comment: thank you for your support. I already tried this thing and it's working. I am updating my answer here.